# I think I only installed xfce as a desktop environment in kali linux , however seemingly there is 2 desktop environments which exist in my computer

Tags: kali-linux, xfce, gui

I think I only chose xfce to install kali linux to my computer .

However as I open a gui-window of files,folders , sometimes I get a different GUI .

Concretely , as I open a window of files normally , I get the kind of below one .

[image]

And as I open a window of files via some different way, I got the kind of below one .

[image]

I much prefer the second gui since it is really lightweight .

How can I uninstall the first gui?

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you say "open a window of files _via some different way_", what do you mean? How does it differ from the first way?

Comment: Sorry for my late response . At least as I open the window via "open file in the directory" led me to open the second file manager .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first file manager seems `nautilus`, it is the one installed with GNOME.
Use `apt remove nautilus` to remove it.

You can use `tasksel` to list the installed DEs (like GNOME and XFCE).

Search in the file manager in help/settings something like `About files`, so you can see the name of the app.

With `xdg-mime default org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop inode/directory` you can set the default file manager, with that command you set `nautilus`.

That command modifies the `~/.config/mimeapps.list` file.